# Processing: send and receive custom events

Tags: java, events, processing

is it possible to create simple custom events in Processing similar to as3?

```
dispatch(new Event("HEY"));
myObject.addEventListener("HEY",callBack);
```

Comment: You have to use `Observer` and `Observable`. See this [thread on the Processing forum](http://forum.processing.org/topic/custom-events-event-listener).

Comment: Is this Java-related? If so, you should tag your question as such.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to implement the observer-pattern yourself. Here is a small example on how to do so in Java: [Stackoverflow: Create a custom event in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java)