# Event handling in java, for a vb.net expert

Tags: java, events, event-handling

I found tons of posts about handling events of existing java classes, but nothing about creating a class with events from scratch.
What is the translation to java of this vb.net snippet?

```
Public Class TestClass
    Event TestEvent()
    Sub TestFunction()
        RaiseEvent TestEvent()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents TC As New TestClass
    Sub OnTestEvent() Handles TC.TestEvent
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good link on the "theory" behind the Java event model:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/awt/1.3/designspec/events.html

And here's a link illustrating how to create your own, custom events:

- http://castever.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/how-to-create-your-own-events-in-java/

And here's a really good example from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java):

```
// REFERENCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java
import java.util.*;

interface HelloListener {
    public void someoneSaidHello();
}


class Initiater {
    List<HelloListener> listeners = new ArrayList<HelloListener>();

    public void addListener(HelloListener toAdd) {
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!!");

        // Notify everybody that may be interested.
        for (HelloListener hl : listeners)
            hl.someoneSaidHello();
    }
}


class Responder implements HelloListener {
    @Override
    public void someoneSaidHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello there...");
    }
}


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Initiater initiater = new Initiater();
        Responder responder = new Responder();

        initiater.addListener(responder);

        initiater.sayHello();
    }
}
```

The key is:

1) create an "interface" that defines your "event" (such as the events in the AWT event model)

2) create a class that "implements" this event (analogous to "callbacks" in languages like C - and effectively what VB does for you automagically with the "Event" type).

'Hope that helps ... at least a little bit!

Comment: I just want to add, that event handling is generally solved using the Observer design pattern. @paulsm4 provided you one example of that. If you search on google "observer pattern" you will find lots of literature about that. Here is one more example: http://searchdaily.net/observer-pattern-java-example/

Comment: @Paulo Silva - you're absolutely correct.  And in fact the example above was explicitly written as an example of [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Thanks, it helps, but after looking at your answer I have another question: Is it possible to create two different listeners for two instances of the same class? Something like:  
`Sub Obj1OnEvent() Hndles Obj.Event
Sub Obj2OnEvent() Hndles Obj.Event`