# Java wait for event and get value

Tags: java, function, return

I have a function, which sends a message to a Server, and another function which would be called if the answer arrives. So I want to return the parameter of the recive function in the request function. How can I do this ?

```
private Answer request(User user){
 //perform request
 //wait for answer but how
}

public void recive(Answer answer){
  //I want the answer parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont simply wait. You create your custom listener : look here
[Create a custom event in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java)
You need to call this event with the parameters YOU specify

Comment: Just a quick note,Zarkopafilis solution refers to a programming methodology named [Event-Driven Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).