# Is it important to always pass argument to event Handler in java?

Tags: java, swing, api, events, event-handling

Well,as far as i know, the event object passed as an argument to the event handler function in Java, holds the additional information about the event.
So, that means it might not be important at times to pass that argument until we require it.

But then, that's not the case...since it throws an error if the object parameter is missing.
For example, this would throw an error..

```
public void actionPerformed() {     //since the event object parameter is missing

        button.setText("Clicked");
    }
```

why is it so?
It's just a waste at times to pass the parameter, so why is there no method in the Swing/AWT Java API that allows event handlers consisting of no parameters at all?
That would really comfort a lot.
 NO?

Comment: It doesn't "thrown an error". Rather it's a compilation error because a particular interface hasn't been implemented - make sure to *read* and *post* the actual error indicators (this is why I downvoted). If you make your *own* events/event handlers, then you can specify whatever parameters are required (possibly none); but if you use *existing* events, then you have to play by their defined rules.

Comment: @user2864740 can we create our own event handler?

Comment: Sure, if you create your own even source (maybe a control?). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java

Comment: @user2864740 That's really useful! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's important, the parameter forms part of the contract as stated by the interface.

An `interface` describes what is expected of implementations.

```
public interface ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt);
}
```

In order for a class to be able to call any implementation of `ActionListener`, it must provide not only the name of the method, but any parameters that it (the `interface`) lists.

```
public void actionPerformed() { 
    button.setText("Clicked");
}
```

Does not meet the requirements of the contract for the `ActionListener` and therefore can not be called.  In fact, assuming that you class `implements  ActionListener`, this will not compile unless you provide an implementation of the form method signature (`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)`).

If you don't want to use the `evt` object, then ignore it.

Comment: why is there no contract that specifies Event Handlers without a parameter?

Comment: You'd have to ask the designers of the API.  I would imagine it they never fore saw a situation where you wouldn't need the event object.