# What should be passed to the constructor as the source?

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, listener

I have a FormPanel class with a JButton, which has an ActionListener. I also have a subclass of EventObject calles FormPanelEvent. My question is about the ActionListeners' actionPerformed() method:
If I instantiate FormPanelEvent, do I pass the FormPanel object or the JButton as the source? I have seen other people pass 'this', but isn't the JButton the actual source?

```
public class FormPanel extends JPanel {

private JLabel usernameLabel, passwordLabel;
private JTextField usernameField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JButton submitButton, clearButton;

private Collection<FormPanelListener> formPanelListeners = new ArrayList<>();

public FormPanel() {

... 

    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String username = usernameField.getText().trim();
            char[] password = passwordField.getPassword();

            FormPanelEvent e = new FormPanelEvent(this or submitButton)
        }

    });

...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with `FormPanel` in the `FormPanelEvent`. It want the complete functionality available in `FormPanelEvent` class then you can pass `this` otherwise if you want to play with source I.e. Button only then you can pass `submitButton`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it is more likely that `submitButton` is the source for the event because the starting event is raised when you click on the button.

You need to make submit button `final` or a member field of the class in order to have an explicit access to it's reference in that actionListener anonymous class.

Good Luck.