# Upload complete event using HttpPost

Tags: java, http, events, file-upload, raise

My app uploads an image to the server. In order to execute an uploading, I use the `HttpPost` class. Here is the relevant code fragment:

```java
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("%PATH_TO_SERVER_PAGE%");
    
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Connection error: " + e.toString());
}
```

How can I raise an event and know if the uploading has been successfully finished to be sure that the file is already on a server?

Comment: Once you are done with httpclient.execute that means you are finished uploading, otherwise it goes into the catch section. By the way, it's discouraged to catch Exception, try to narrow it down.

Comment: Also, create a custom event handler and raise it once you are done with httpclient.execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the implementation of the ***Observer Design Pattern*** would be a suitable solution.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6270150/462347