# Can I have 2 fragments inside of another fragment that interacts with each other?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main activity that have a navigation drawer in it which goes to many other fragments. One particular fragment A have 2 fragments (B & C) inside it.

Is it possible to have a fragment that acts like an activity which caters 2 other fragments inside it? **(update: yes)** If so, can the two child fragments interacts with each other? (e.g. passing data - a button click in fragment C populate a list (recycler view) in fragment B).

Comment: yes, you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

> can the two child fragments interacts with each other? (e.g. passing
>   data - a button click in fragment C populate a list (recycler view) in
>   fragment B).

Yes, Use custom events and event handling for example. In that case you aren't really depend on particularly FragmentB.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java) is how to implement a custom event.